# Shell Script for Deployment in AWS s3

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

we have an static website build in Angular 2 which is hosted on s3.
The website use an API which is maded in AWS Gateway + Lambda Function.

For our Frontend Deployment we like to use an EC2 Instance with Linux, where we start an `Shell` script which will handle our building and upload from EC2 to our S3.

```
#!/bin/bash

#pull from branch
git checkout --force "$1"
git pull 

#build the app
ng build --production 
cd dist

#uplaod to S3

$counter = find dist -type f | wc -l

#staging parameter
 if ["$1" = "staging"]
  then aws s3 cp dist s3://STAGINBUCKET --recursive
  #[1]

#live parameter
 if ["$1" = "live"]
  then aws s3 cp dist s3://LIVEBUCKT --recursive
  #[1]

#Errorhandler
else echo "parameter $1 error"
```

Our Problem is that we cant upload a whole folder to S3, so we need an for / while loop which will upload evry file to our Bucket.

i tryed: [1]

```
for i in `seq 1 $counter`
 do
  #upload to file on position $i in folder dist
done
```

Which wont work for me.

If someone knows a better way to handle Deployment in AWS I would appreciate an tip.

Thanks for help in Advance!

Comment: Why can't you upload the entire folder to S3? What problem are you having with the aws s3 cp --recursive command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can copy a whole directory. From `aws s3 sync help`:

```
NAME
       sync -

DESCRIPTION
       Syncs  directories  and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated
       files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates  fold-
       ers in the destination if they contain one or more files.
```

Comment: since im already in my `dist` folder can I run `aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket` and it will work as i want?

Comment: Indeed: `cd tmp; touch foo bar baz; aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket/label/sub/`